# Should I use pragma marks or create a Category to divide my code?

Tags: ios

I want to create a cleaner aspect for my code but I'm not quite sure what do the coding guidelines for iOS / standards state about this topic. I'll take a `UITableViewDataSource` for example:

I have the possibility to create a `pragma mark`, name it "UITableViewDataSource methods" and place those methods underneath.

An alternative (which I'm quite looking forward to following) is to create a separate `Category` where I could place those methods so that when someone reads my main file to exactly see only the important methods / flow of my code.

What would you a professional do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While both can bring clarity and readability, let's not mix code comments and code architecture.

```
// MARK: - is for clearly grouping methods with some commonality
```

Categories (Extensions in **Swift**)

> add new functionality to an existing class, structure, or enumeration type. This includes the ability to extend types for which you do not have access to the original source code.

*Professionals do not document their code nearly enough.*

Comment: I didn't understand the "do not document their code nearly enough". What did you mean?

Comment: IMHO, many engineers treat comments like turn signals: *why bother since I know where I'm going*. On the other hand, many comments are not about the *design*, but the *implementation*. I rarely need the actual `code`  (the *implementation*) to be documented. What I need is documented **design**: the overall `logic`, `intent` and `context`.

Comment: I will, but keep in mind that I read the iOS Coding guidelines, but didn't learn much about aspects like I asked in my question.